# How to remove my "x" close Button in marker InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

### How to remove my "X" Button in my marker InfoWindow?

[
            "Aubrica the Mermaid (nee: Aubry Alexis)",
            36.8618, -76.203,
            5,
            "Myke Irving/ Georgia Mason",
            "USAVE Auto Rental",
            "Virginia Auto Rental on Virginia Beach Blvd",
            "assets/images/1.jpg",
            "found"
        ]
    ]

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    // center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.8857, -76.2599),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker, this);
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                document.getElementById("map").style.width = "50%";
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                document.getElementById("data").style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = locations[i][0] + "<br />" + locations[i][4] + "<br />" + locations[i][5] + "<br />" + locations[i][6] + "<br />" + '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + locations[i][7] + '" /></div></div>';
                document.getElementById("button").style.display = "block";
            });
        }
    })(marker, i, infowindow));
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
        infowindow.close();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a CSS hack that may do the job, but it might not be so good if the URL changes in the future...

```
    <style>
img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png"] {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Try inspecting the page to get the correct image resource... as it may be...

```
https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt6.png
```

Rather than the one i quoted.

Comment: use img[src*="mapcnt6.png"] to prevent the http/https issue.

Comment: Lovely shorthand.